# Unable to connect netbeans to mysql server, getting exceptions

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have been trying to connect netbeans to mysql server for days now, I re-installed mysql and changed the authentication settings; Changed my connector/j jar file.

I do get the "connection succeeded!" message when I make a connection to a database, I can view their data.But I keep getting these exceptions:-

> java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
>   java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Here's my code:-

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String s="";
    try{
    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mma"; 
    String user="root";
    String password="Reshteenbb4905";
    Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password); 
    //Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    //
    Statement stat=c.createStatement();
    ResultSet result=stat.executeQuery("select ProductID from product "
            + "where ProductID='1'");
    ResultSet result2=stat.executeQuery("select * from product");
    while(result2.next()){
        int i=result2.getInt(1);
        s=result2.getString(2);
        String description=result2.getString(3);
        double d= result2.getDouble(4);
    }
    result.close();
    //ResultSet result2=stat.executeQuery("select * from product");
    //boolean cursor=result.next();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        for(Throwable t:e){
            System.out.println(t);
            e.getMessage();
        }
      //  e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Comment: What line, specifically, do you get that error message on?

Comment: Try declaring variables(i, description, d) out side the while loop.

Comment: Well, according to the stacktrace I get the error message on: -  Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);